# How to align set of tspan elements by center?

Tags: svg, alignment, tspan

I googled a lot of ways how to align set of `tspan` by center, but I need something else. I need to align the set of `tspan` elements by center and each element should be aligned by the left side with other elements.

On the picture below you can see what I'm trying to reach.
[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f68hzjt9/)

I tried to add one more `tspan` element as a wrapper for other and set to it `text-anchor: middle`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I would use JavaScript to calculate the offset for the first `tspan` as half the difference of length between the two `tspan` elements

```js
let tspans = document.querySelectorAll("tspan");
let offset = (tspans[1].getComputedTextLength() - tspans[0].getComputedTextLength())/2
tspans[0].setAttributeNS(null,"dx", -offset)
```

```css
svg {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 400 100">
    <circle r="3" cx="200" cy="50" fill="red">
    </circle>

    <text y="50" text-anchor="middle"><!--
      --><tspan x="200" >First label</tspan><!--
      --><tspan x="200" dy="15">Second long long long label</tspan>
   </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

My destination goal was to align group of different `tspan` by the center. I appreciate @enxaneta help. I posted my own answer as I stuck with some interesting sub defect. The last `tspan` row wasn't left aligned. I saw 3 or 5 px space. It was caused by XML spaces. You need to delete spaces between `tspan` elements in order to get rid of this issue.

[image]

```js
 let tspans = document.querySelectorAll("tspan");
 let indexOfLongestRow = 0;

 for(let i = 0; i < tspans.length; i++) {
  if(tspans[indexOfLongestRow].getComputedTextLength() < tspans[i].getComputedTextLength()) {
    indexOfLongestRow = i;
   }
 }

 console.log(tspans[indexOfLongestRow]);

 for(let i = 0; i < tspans.length; i++) {
    let offset = (tspans[indexOfLongestRow].getComputedTextLength() - tspans[i].getComputedTextLength())/2;

     console.log(offset);

  tspans[i].setAttributeNS(null, "dx", -offset);
 }
```

```css
svg {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 400 500">
    <circle r="3" cx="200" cy="50" fill="red">
    </circle>

   <text y="50" text-anchor="middle">
     <tspan x="200" dy="15">Second long long long label</tspan><tspan x="200" dy="15">This is a longest label that i have here ergrtgrtgregregregerg</tspan><tspan x="200" dy="15">This is a longest label that i have here ergrtgrtgregregregerg</tspan><tspan x="200" dy="15">First label</tspan><tspan x="200" dy="15">First label dfhdfhh</tspan><tspan x="200" dy="15">This is a longest label that i have here ergrtgrtgregregregerg</tspan><tspan x="200" dy="15">First label rth th rthththsrth</tspan><tspan x="200" dy="15">First label rthrth rthrt 5tyjey yejetyj tyjtyj teyjteyj</tspan><tspan x="200" dy="15">First label reghregregregregregrge</tspan></text>
</svg>
```